# I'm trying to write a function that computes the numeric root of a number in C++, but get an error after compiling

Tags: c++

```
int main(){
int sum_digits(int tiv) {
    int sum = 0;
    while (tiv > 0) {
        sum += tiv % 10;
        tiv /= 10;
    };
    return sum;
};

int num_root(int num) {
  int root = sum_digit(int num);
  while(root > 9) {
      sum_digits(int root);
      };
  return root;
};
return 0;
}
```

This is the code that I have written the first function calculates the sum of the digis of a number. The second function uses a loop to calculate the sum of the digits repeatedly until a one digit numer is obtained (i.e. the numeric root).

But when I compile the code, this is what I get

> 5:29: error: a function-definition is not allowed here before '{' token  (the first line of main)
>
> 22:2: error: expected '}' at end of input  (the last line)

Some guidance would be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: Move your functions outside main().

Comment: You define a function inside of a function in line 2, I don't think you really intended to do this.

Comment: my task is to calculate the numeric root by using the function sum_digits(int tiv), so I need intended to do it.

Comment: @Power No, you intended to _call_ `sum_digits()` in `main()`.  There's a difference between defining a function and calling it.  To call it, define `sum_digits()` outside `main()`, then add a line like `int i = sum_digits(5);` inside `main()`.

Comment: @JustinTime ahhh, okay I got the part about declaring outside main(). So by the same logic I should define num_root() outside main() too, right?

Comment: @Power Yep.  Trying to define one function inside another function is a syntax error, so both have to be outside `main()`.

Comment: @JustinTime Ok, I got it, I guess my main mistake was trying to declare functions in main(), anyway thanks for the tips.

Comment: @Power You're welcome.  Don't feel bad about it, if you were; everyone makes silly mistakes when they're learning, and this is probably one of the more common ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As people have indicated in the comments, you shouldn't define a function inside of another function like this.

```
int main(){
   // This is defined inside of main
   int sum_digits(int tiv) {
      int sum = 0;
      while (tiv > 0) {
```

I'd always encourage proper code indentation as that would have made this problem much more obvious.

Also, this isn't the correct way to do a function call:

```
int root = sum_digit(int num);
```

You don't need to include the `int` again here (in fact, it's not syntactically valid to do so) - it's already clear from the rest of your code that `num` is an `int`.

Same thing here:

```
while(root > 9) {
  sum_digits(int root);
};
```

Also, you don't actually do anything with the return value of `sum_digits`, so this will literally do nothing. It will either be an infinite loop (if `root` is greater than 9), since the value of `root` never changes, or the loop won't ever run (if `root` is less than 9).

One final point: in order to have this program actually do anything, you'll have to call the functions from your `main` method with some value. Right now even if you fix the compilation errors the program won't work because you don't actually determine what values you want the root of and you never actually call the functions you wrote.

Comment: Okay I get the point about declaring the type of a variable again is syntactically invalid.
Regarding inputs and outputs, my task was just to write the function that returns the value, not prints it out, so I never bothered with those.
But regarding the operation performed with `while`, is it wrong to use `root > 9` as a means of determining whether the integer has more than one digit?

Comment: @Power The problem I was referring to is that, if the loop runs at all, it'll be an infinite loop because you never actually modify the value of root after you assign it and you never actually do anything with the value returned by sum_digits. Thus, if root starts off being greater than 9, it'll **always** be greater than 9 because it's never actually modified.

Comment: Okay I will try to use another way instead of `while`, I now see that it will run infinitely, thanks for clearing it out.

Comment: @Power the problem isn't the while loop in and of itself, the main issue is that the fact that root is never being modified makes it infinite.

Answer (score 0):

defining functions within functions is nothing you should do in c/c++. I think gcc supports this, but afaik its not standard conforming.

just declare and define your functions not within other functions. use anonymous namespaces if you want to hide them from your public api